# Vue looping nested JSON troubles

Tags: javascript, json, loops, vue.js, vue-component

I'm having a little problem accessing a nested JSON file.

Here's a small chunk of a larger JSON file:

```
{
    "first": "SOME_TEXT",
    "second": 1,
    "items": [
        {
            "volumeInfo": {
                "first": "SOME_TEXT",
                "second": [
                    "SOME_TEXT"
                ],
                "imageLinks": {
                    "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=hpTEDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
                    "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=hpTEDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

..And here's my Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <b-container v-for="(res, index) in res.items" :key="index">
              <!-- Img path from response -->
              <b-img :src="res.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail"></b-img>
      </b-container>
    </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Component',
  data () {
    return {
      res: '',
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    fetch('API-URL-HERE')
      .then(res => {
        return res.json()
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.res = res
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to loop a large JSON file, so that I can get the "smallThumbnail" to the Vue component via looping. When I write the code like in my Vue component, I get ***TypeError: Cannot read property 'smallTumbnail' of undefined***

What's wrong with my Vue code? How can I access an item from JSON file, that's nested one step further?

Comment: Is it a typo error in your question or you're actually trying to access `smallTumbnail` without H letter in v-for?

Comment: Thanks for the catch, It's actually correct in the code, but made a typo while writing here :(

Comment: Are your response returning a valid json object or a string? I've tested your code on jsFiddle and it worked well.

Comment: Here's the URL for the JSON: https://api.myjson.com/bins/lj2ie

Comment: Can you show `console.log(res)`?

Comment: Is there any fast way to allow console.log while using npm run serve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using:

```
<b-img v-if="res.volumeInfo.imageLinks" :src="res.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail"></b-img>
```

Instead of

```
<b-img :src="res.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail"></b-img>
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is that the JSON file is totally mixed. Not every instance has imageLinks, and the amount of nested data varies. That's why the loop breaks when it encounters a nest that does not have "imageLinks". The JSON file is intentionally shuffled to make life (and programming) a bit harder.